# Spring + Thymeleaf + Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I would like to know how to override the css from Bootstrap. This is what I have tried so far. I created a separate css file and there I am calling the Bootstrap css classes and making some changes, but I do not see differences on the class that I have changed.

Html and css file

```css
.table {
    border-color: crimson;
}

.table-striped {
    border-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Spring Core Online Tutorial - List Products</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
          rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"
            th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js}"></script>

    <link href="../../static/css/spring-core.css"
          th:href="@{css/spring-core.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(products)}">
        <h2>Product List</h2>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Image URL</th>
                <th>Show</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="product : ${products}">
                <td th:text="${product.id}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.description}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.price}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.imageUrl}"></td>
                <td><a th:href="${'/product/show/' + product.id}">View</a> </td>
                <td><a th:href="${'/product/edit/' + product.id}">Edit</a> </td>
                <td><a th:href="${'/product/delete/' + product.id}">Delete</a> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <a href="/product/new">New Product</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.designfreed</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-mvc</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>spring-mvc</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Hope anyone could help!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: make sure that your custom css is loading after the bootstrap file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, I was missing a slash on my html when importing my css file

This was my original html file

```html
<link href="../../static/css/spring-core.css"
          th:href="@{css/spring-core.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
```

This is my html with the mistake corrected

```html
<link href="../../static/css/spring-core.css"
          th:href="@{/css/spring-core.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
```

Thanks for the answer as they helped me to target the specific parts that I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Border color is not applied to the `.table`, `.table-striped` classes, it is set in Bootstrap with the following selector:

```
.table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td,     
.table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Make sure you use the selectors used by Bootstrap to make your customisations.

Answer (score 0):

you can't see the effects because you didn't specified **border type** and **border width** properties .set that properties to see the effect.I'm added an snippet below.
use border:border_width border_type border_colour; to set your border

```css
.table {
    border:1px solid  crimson;
}

.table-striped {
    border:1px solid  crimson ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Spring Core Online Tutorial - List Products</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
          rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"
            th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js}"></script>

    <link href="../../static/css/spring-core.css"
          th:href="@{css/spring-core.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(products)}">
        <h2>Product List</h2>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Image URL</th>
                <th>Show</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="product : ${products}">
                <td th:text="${product.id}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.description}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.price}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.imageUrl}"></td>
                <td><a th:href="${'/product/show/' + product.id}">View</a> </td>
                <td><a th:href="${'/product/edit/' + product.id}">Edit</a> </td>
                <td><a th:href="${'/product/delete/' + product.id}">Delete</a> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <a href="/product/new">New Product</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```